Minimum number of edge colors in a certain bipartite graph
I have a problem that can be modeled as  a graph edges coloring.
Starting from a $K_{5,5}$ graph, remove $5$ edges none of which is adjacent to another one of them.
What is the minimum number of colors for the graph edges, such that there is no $K_{2,2}$ subgraph with all its edges of the same color?
The general problem is:
Starting from a $K_{n,n}$ graph, remove $n$ edges none of which is adjacent to another one of them.
What is the minimum number of colors for the graph edges, such that there is no $K_{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor,2}$ subgraph with all its edges of the same color?
Can we say something about this problem?

Two colors should be enough for all $n \ge 5$. (If $n=4$, three colors are required to avoid a monochromatic $K_{1,2}$, because no vertex can have degree $2$ in any color.)
When looking at $K_{2n,2n}$ minus a perfect matching, we are trying to avoid a monochromatic $K_{n-1,2}$. When looking at $K_{2n-1,2n-1}$ minus a perfect matching, we are also trying to avoid a monochromatic $K_{n-1,2}$. Therefore solving the even cases is enough to solve the odd cases before them.
Here is a special-case solution for $n=6$, where my general solution doesn't work:
. 1 1 1 0 0
1 . 1 0 1 0
1 1 . 0 0 1
0 1 0 . 1 0
0 0 1 0 . 1
1 0 0 1 0 .

The rows are vertices on one side of $K_{6,6}$, and the columns are vertices on the other side of $K_{6,6}$. A 0 represents one color, a 1 represents the other, and . represents a missing edge. We cannot find two rows and two columns such that all four intersections have the same number: 0 or 1.
For $n=2k$ where $k\ge 4$, let's number the vertices on one side $x_1, \dots, x_{2k}$ and the vertices on the other side $y_1, \dots, y_{2k}$, with the edges $x_i y_i$ missing. We will color the edges red and blue by the following rule:

All edges $x_i y_j$ with $i \le k$ and $j\le k$ are blue.
All edges $x_i y_j$ with $i > k$ and $j > k$ are blue.
All edges $x_i y_{i+k}$ and $x_{i+k}y_i$ for $i=1, \dots, k$ are blue.
All other edges are red.

This is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, so it's enough to check that there is no monochromatic $K_{k-1,2}$ with $2$ vertices from the $x$-side and $k-1$ vertices from the $y$-side. So let's consider two vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ and check that they're not part of a monochromatic $K_{k-1,2}$:
Case 1. $i \le k$ and $j \le k$.
There are $k-2$ vertices with blue edges to both $x_i$ and $x_j$: the vertices $y_1, \dots, y_k$, except for $y_i$ and $y_j$ (which are missing an edge to $x_i$ and to $x_j$ respectively). There are $k-2$ vertices with red edges to both $x_i$ and $x_j$: the vertices $y_{k+1}, \dots, y_{2k}$, except for $y_{k+i}$ and $y_{k+j}$ (which have a blue edge to $x_i$ and to $x_j$ respectively). Therefore at most we can get a monochromatic $K_{2,k-2}$ here.
Case 2. $i>k$ and $j>k$.
This case is nearly the same as Case 1, but it is $y_1, \dots, y_k$ except for $y_{i-k}$ and $y_{j-k}$ which have the red edges to $x_i$ and $x_j$, and $y_{k+1}, \dots, y_{2k}$ except for $y_i$ and $y_j$ which have the blue edges.
Case 3. $i \le k$ and $j>k$.
Among $y_1, \dots, y_k$, all vertices that have an edge to $x_i$ have a blue edge to $x_i$. Most of them have a red edge to $x_j$, except for $y_{j-k}$, so here there is at most one vertex with the same color of edge to $x_i$ and to $x_j$.
Among $y_{k+1}, \dots, y_{2k}$, all vertices that have an edge to $x_j$ have a blue edge to $x_j$. Most of them have a red edge to $x_i$, except for $y_{i+k}$, so here there is also at most one vertex with the same color of edge to $x_i$ and to $x_j$.
Altogether, we get at most a monochromatic $K_{2,2}$ from this case.
Case 4. $i>k$ and $j \le k$.
This case is the same as Case 3, swapping the roles of $x_i$ and $x_j$.
